# How to disable player-player/player-monster collisions and keep the OnTrigger/OnCollision hooks?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, networking

I'm developing a network game. Players and enemies have attached `Rigidbodies`, move with physics forces, stops on kinematic colliders (walls) - everything works pretty well. Now it's the time for player-player and player-monster coliisions.

In my case, the player should be unpushable, even by other players and monsters.

The problem with that is if all 'moving/non-kinematic' objects have rigidbodies, they can move/push each other as they move - which is wrong in my case. I came up with an idea that I'll disable collisions between these objects through layers and did that.

I also wrote a script which pushes the object back (in the opposite direction) when triggered which I want to apply.

The problem is here, that I need to preserve the original collider (non-trigger) so the player can be stopped by walls AND I need to detect other players in `OnTriggerEnter()` so I can push them back so they don't overlap.

This is quite easy - I need two colliders attached to the player:

- **a non-trigger one** - responsible for the ground, walls, physics driven
- **a trigger one** - for interaction with players and enemies (to push them)

I also need to disable built-in collisions between players through the physics layers and listen for `"Player"` and `"Monster"` tags in `OnTrigger()`.

Does this all make sense? How would you improve this? Is there a quicker way to achieve this? Two colliders seem not that bad - but it's still two instead of one.

In order to visualize what I want to achieve:

[image]

Games I know have collisions like this are `Diablo 3` and `League of Legends` probably.

Comment: Did you profile? Is it a bottleneck? The tone of your question implies you are trying to do premature optimization.

Comment: To be honest, I'm trying to figure out how to implement this, so it will be clean and easy to adjust/edit. As this is a popular scenario and I couldn't find anything similar, I'm asking for an advice.

Comment: Did you actually achive this or not? I understand from  your question that you already have a system working.